# how to send a parameter in a session?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing an application in asp.net mvc

I am stuck to send a parameter to a session, like the example below.
I want to send this parameter in this session

```
 @Html.ActionLink("listaydroit", "aydroits", new { iddem = item.id_demande })
 @Session["id"] = iddem
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it in the controller directly:

```
Session["id"] = iddem;
```

Or you can use C# code in view .shtml file, included in `@{` and `}`, like this:

```
@{
    Session["id"] = iddem;
}
```

To use the session, you can do the same as assignment.

Comment: yes, I know, but it generates an error because the controller waits for the value of the parameter,I just want to put it in the session, but use it in other controllers

Comment: `Session` can be used in all controllers in the whole site. What you could do is: receiving the value in the controller, storing it in `Session`, then you can use the `Session` in other controllers.

Comment: but, the first controller where I send the parameter will wait for a value and if I don't use it in this controller it will generate an error
sorry for my English is not good

Comment: OK, could you please post your codes of the two controllers and the view? It may help us to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your solution, but it generates an error 
ok,I tried to use in this controller, but I still have an error 
I resume the codes 
this for to send the value

```
 <td>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">

                                            //value iddem 
 @Html.ActionLink("valider", "aydroit", new { iddem = item.id_demande })


            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

the code to recover the value and to use in this controller and this request

```
 public ActionResult listaydroi(int iddem)
    {
        int idutilisateur = int.Parse(Session["id_utilisateur"].ToString());


        var VC = (from a in db.employe

                  join b in db.utilisateur
                  on a.id_employe equals b.idemploye_utilisateur

                  join c in db.demande
                  on b.id_utilisateur equals c.idutilisateur_demande

                  join e in db.aydroit
                  on a.id_employe equals e.idemploye_aydroit

        where b.id_utilisateur == idutilisateur && c.id_demande == iddem                     

                  select new
                  {
                      e.nom_aydroit,
                      e.prenom_aydroit,
                      c.id_demande

                  }).FirstOrDefault();


        Session["nom_ayd"] = VC.nom_aydroit.ToString();
        Session["prenom_ayd"] = VC.prenom_aydroit.ToString();
        Session["id_demande"] = VC.id_demande.ToString();



        List<employe> employes = db.employe.ToList();
        List<demande> demandes = db.demande.ToList();
        List<utilisateur> utilisateurs = db.utilisateur.ToList();
        List<aydroit> aydroits = db.aydroit.ToList();

        List<valideyd > valideayds = db.valideyd.ToList();

        try
        {



            var CV = (from a in employes

                      join b in utilisateurs
                      on a.id_employe equals b.idemploye_utilisateur

                      join c in demandes
                      on b.id_utilisateur equals c.idutilisateur_demande

                      join e in aydroits
                      on a.id_employe equals e.idemploye_aydroit

                      where b.id_utilisateur == idutilisateur 

                      select new AydroitViewModel
                      {
                          aydroitlist = e,
                          demandelist = c,


                      });

            return View(CV);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }

    }
```

But I generates this erreur

```
http://localhost:61725/demandes/aydroit?iddem=42
Erreur du serveur dans l'application
```

And thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question
the mistake was in the syntax

Correction :

```
 <a href='/aydroits/listaydroit/@item.id_demande' class="btn btn-outline-primary  py-2 ">ADD</a>
```